# Проблемы с установкой Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio

[[image: Выдает такую проблему[1]]

Выдает проблему при установке, не знаю, что делать, уже день не могу установить VSC 2015, кто знает, что делать, хелп

Comment: Посмотрите log file и лежащий рядом лог для упавшего компонента - там будет конкретная ошибка. Иначе получите советы наугад.

Answer (score 1):

Вот полезный [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855177/multiple-errors-installing-visual-studio-2015-community-edition/34008086#34008086) от [@BjörnBlissing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4244376/bj%C3%B6rn-blissing):

> After the failed install you have to repair the 2015 vc
>   redistributables and restart the visual studio installer.
>
> The redistributable installer is messed up, it mixes up 64bit and
>   32bit dll's. You can check if you have this problem by looking at the
>   vcruntime140.dll file size. Search your windows folder for
>   "vcruntime140" you should see 4 files (64 and 32 bit in both release &
>   debug versions). If any files have the same size, you need to run a
>   repair on the redistributable.
>
> On my system the 32 bit dll is 83,3KB, the 64 bit is 86,6KB ( release
>   versions )

**Перевод:**

> После неудачной установки вы должны исправить распространяемый пакет
>   2015 vc и перезапустить программу установки Visual Studio.
>
> Установщики распространяемых пакетов перепутались и это смешало
>   библиотеки dll 64 бит и 32 бит. Вы можете проверить наличие у Вас
>   данной проблемы, глядя на размер файла *vcruntime140.dll*. Через поиск
>   в папке windows для *vcruntime140* Вы должны увидеть 4 файла (64 и 32
>   бит в обоих выпусках и версиях отладки). Если какие-либо файлы имеют
>   одинаковый размер, Вам нужно запустить исправление на распространяемом
>   пакете.
>
> На моей системе DLL 32 бит 83,3KB, 64 бит 86,6KB (релиз версии).

Comment: Ответ стоит перевести на русский, или по крайней мере описать его основную мысль.

Comment: У меня только 64 и 86 бит
Когда я начал поиск файлов, появилось куча vcruntime 140

Comment: stackoverflow - это не форум